# Why isnt my program not reading the other variables?

Tags: python-3.x, math, trigonometry

I'm new to this whole programming thing and slowly picking up a few things on the internet but i cant seem to find a solution or just dont understand it.  Why won't the program read the other elif statements? This is my very first project. Ill appreciate any tips and advice. Open to any suggestions and opinions, Thanks!

```
#inputing
unknown = " "
while unknown != "exit":
    unknown = input("Please enter unknown: ").lower()
    angle = int(input("Please enter given angle: "))
#if base
    if unknown == "base" or "a":
        side = input("Height(b) or Hypotenuse(c)? ").lower()
        if side == "height" or "b":
            height = int(input("Please enter given height: "))
            base = int(height * tan(radians(angle)))
            print(">> The base is: " + str(base))
        else:
            hypotenuse = int(input("Please enter given hypotenuse: "))
            base = int(hypotenuse * cos(radians(angle)))
            print(">> The base is: " + str(base))

#if height
    elif unknown == "height" or "b":
        side = (input("Base(a) or Hypotenuse(c)?  ")).lower()
        if side == "base" or "a":
            base = int(input("Please enter given base: "))
            height = int(input(base * tan(radians(angle))))
            print(">> The height is: " + str(height))
        else:
            hypotenuse = int(input("Please enter given hypotenuse: "))
            height = int(hypotenuse * cos(radians(angle)))
            print(">> The height is: " + str(height))
    elif unknown == "exit":
        break
    else:
        print("I don't understand that..")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condition should be `if unknown == "base" or unknown == "a":` and `elif unknown == "height" or unknown == "b":`.

In `unknown == "base" or "a"` the first condition is False `unknown == "base"` and `"a"` is True, which results in result True `"a"`.

```
#inputing
unknown = " "
while unknown != "exit":
    unknown = input("Please enter unknown: ").lower()
    angle = int(input("Please enter given angle: "))
#if base
    if unknown == "base" or unknown == "a":
        side = input("Height(b) or Hypotenuse(c)? ").lower()
        if side == "height" or "b":
            height = int(input("Please enter given height: "))
            base = int(height * tan(radians(angle)))
            print(">> The base is: " + str(base))
        else:
            hypotenuse = int(input("Please enter given hypotenuse: "))
            base = int(hypotenuse * cos(radians(angle)))
            print(">> The base is: " + str(base))

#if height
    elif unknown == "height" or unknown == "b":
        side = (input("Base(a) or Hypotenuse(c)?  ")).lower()
        if side == "base" or "a":
            base = int(input("Please enter given base: "))
            height = int(input(base * tan(radians(angle))))
            print(">> The height is: " + str(height))
        else:
            hypotenuse = int(input("Please enter given hypotenuse: "))
            height = int(hypotenuse * cos(radians(angle)))
            print(">> The height is: " + str(height))
    elif unknown == "exit":
        break
    else:
        print("I don't understand that..")
```

*Please mark the answer as correct if it answers your question.*